# Generate two matrices such that multiplication of these matrices results a symmetric positive definite matrix

Tags: matlab, positive-definite

I want to generate a tall&skinny matrix and a fat&short matrix, such that multiplication of these matrices results a symmetric positive definite matrix.

My inefficient/expensive solution is:

```
A       = rand(5,5);
A       = A + A';
P       = A + n*eye(n);
% P is a symmetric positive definite matrix 
[U,S,V] = svd(P);
X       = U * sqrt(S);
X2      = sqrt(S) * V';
```

`X` and `X2` contain the desired matrices. I do not want to run an expensive operation such as `svd()`. I want to generate two matrices as cheap as possible, i.e., the solution must be fast and must avoid constructing the symmetric positive definite matrix.

The first matrix (`X`) must be tall&skinny.
The second matrix (`X2`) must be fat&short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, that's pretty expensive. You cannot make a positive definite matrix by just multiplying any `skinny * fat`. Instead, you can do one of the following: `skinny' * skinny` or `fat * fat' + c*identity` where `c > 0` where `skinny` and `fat` in the above are fixed (so you're multiply a matrix by its own transpose.

Here's a faster way:

```
m = 5; n = 3; % these can be any natural number as long as n<m
A = rand(m,n); % a tall skinny matrix

posDef = A'*A % will be positive definite n*n matrix with probability 1
```

or you can replace that last line with

```
lambdaMin = 1 % any positive number that you want to be your smallest eigenvalue
posDef = A*A' + lambdaMin*eye(m) % will be positive definite m*m matrix with probability 1
```

**Why this works.** Any finite-dimensional, real positive definite matrix can be decomposed into a sum of dyads of the form $a \otimes a = a a^\top$ (an outer product of a finite-dimensional, real vector and itself). These dyads have rank one, are symmetric, and are in fact positive semidefinite. What we're doing in the code above is just stacking these vectors side by side in a matrix $A$ so that $A^\top A = \sum_{i=1}^m a_i a_i^\top$ where $a_i$ is the $i^{th}$ row of $A$. So long as no one dyads is in the span of the other dyads (which will happen *almost surely* when we randomly generate $A$), the sum of the dyads remains symmetric and has either full-rank or rank as large as the number of elements of the sum (whichever rank is smaller).

Comment: For the first option: First matrix, `A'` is not tall&skinny, it is short&fat. For the second option: How can we obtain tall&skinny and short&fat matrices?

Comment: That's the way to go (up to some typos). But your explanation does not really explain why this works. *Any* matrix can be written as a sum of dyads.  A matrix of the form, $A^TA$ is positive semidefinite because $\langle x, A^TAx\rangle \geq 0$.

Comment: Kadir, I know the first case is not what you asked for, I included it as it is very closely related to the second case.

@Dirk, thanks for the feedback, I added some details to my last paragraph. The poster of the query is encouraged to do further research (using keywords like "dyad" and "positive definite") to better understand the topic if so inclined.

Comment: Forgot to add: Kadir, you cannot have a positive definite matrix arise from *just* `skinny*fat`, where `skinny` and `fat` are finite-dimensional matrices. It's simply not possible. The most you'll get is semi-definite.